# How can sibling components listen to each other's events in Angular12?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, frontend

I am making a booking application and i am stuck on a the results page which displays after a user searches for available seats.Each search result is displayed as a single block as shown in the image. When the user inputs the number of passengers, the block expands to display a form for collecting user  details. I want the currently expanded block to hide the user input form when the user decides to navigate to another block[The search results page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGACO.png)

Comment: This shouldn't be handled in the components. It should be handled in the MVC Controller

Comment: Enumerate the steps you have done in attempt to achieve your desired result. Walk us through, step by step, with some code snippets until we get to your specific issue. There are many ways in achieving "communication" between components. You may use an Angular Service, with or without `rxjs` `Observable`s, you may directly link your components using `@Input`s & `@Outputs` or use a 3rd party state management library like `ngrx`. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69032955/edit) your question, read [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.